# Moving web files to /home/user/ gives permission denied using apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions

I recently created some linux users on my machine and their respective directories were created in the following manner `/home/my_user` so I decided to treat each user as one of my websites.

I moved all my website files over to this directory like so `/home/my_user/public_html/`.

I edited the virtual host in my `httpd.conf` and changed the root directory folder so this is how that looks

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
   DocumentRoot "/home/my_user/public_html"
   ServerName mywebsite.com
   ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
   ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/mywebsite/error_log"
   CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/mywebsite/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Now this virtual host configuration was working perfectly fine with my older document root path that was located at `/var/www/html/mywebsite/public_html` but after changing that to what it is right now, I am getting a permission denied error.

But I followed the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427808/you-dont-have-permission-error-in-apache-in-centos

Even after following the above instructions, when I run the following command: `sudo -u apache ls /home/my_user/public_html`

The server responds with

`ls: cannot open directory /home/my_user/public_html: Permission denied`

Even so, I do not get a permissions denied error when I try to access my site any more, however, now I am redirected to the default page of apache instead of my website.

I am not exactly sure what's wrong any more, if anyone has an idea, it would be great if you guys could help out!

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/my_user/public_html? What does the access log and error logs say when you try access the site?

Comment: The permissions for public_html there is `rwxrwx--- or 077` further more error logs and access logs simply say that access was denied that's all.\

Comment: If you're using Centos, is SElinux enforced? Run 'getenforce'

Comment: command returns `Disabled`

Comment: Also, what are the permissions for /home/my_user? On some distros such as Redhat/Centos it's 700 so the group won't have access to it.

Comment: It's 770, before it was 770 which was the reason the browser showed permission denied. But now the browser just directs to the default apache page.

Comment: I'm trying to replicate the issue on a test box but so far it's working fine (had to restart Apache after changing the directory permissions though). What is the status code being returned? You can run curl -IL http://start.url/ and it'll show you the headers of all the requests and will follow redirects. Also, do you get the same result if you try and access a static asset like an image or css file?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) if I were you to configure a public_html dir in each of your users homedir.

> This module allows user-specific directories to be accessed using the
>   http://example.com/~user/ syntax.

You can enable it for only a subset of users if you'd like:

```
UserDir disabled
UserDir enabled user1 user2 user3
```

With this in place you will probably have more luck with the perms, as it might very well be that with your conf, you're getting an SELinux denial or something on top of your permission errors.

You typically don't want to allow other users access to the users directories, which your approach would require.